# UPDATE values in a table based on certain conditions (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

first question here so bear with me.

I want to update values in a table from with data from additional tables.

**My main table I want updated - Supplier Name, Metric, Performance % )**

My table is pre-populated with suppliers and metrics

- Supplier A, Metric1, performance %(null at present)
- Supplier A, Metric2, performance %(null at present)

I want to update the performance% (currently null) based on the supplier name and metric from Table Metric 1, but also want to update the metric 2 value which comes from Table metric 2.

My problem is that my sql code updates the values in my main table for both lines instead of only updating the line where my 'where condition' states it should.

So instead of ending up with metric 1 = 50% and metric 2 = 100% , I end up with metric 1 = 50% and metric 2 = NULL.

Here is my code.

```
UPDATE MAIN_TABLE 
SET ***PERFORMANCE*** =  CASE WHEN MAIN_TABLE.METRIC_NAME = '***METRIC1***' 
THEN (SELECT AVG (***PERFORMANCE***)
FROM TABLE1)

WHEN MAIN_TABLE.METRIC_NAME = '***METRIC2***' 
THEN  (SELECT AVG (***PERFORMANCE***)
FROM TABLE 2) END;
```

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Please tag just ONE.

Comment: Your query has no WHERE , it updates every row in the MAIN_TABLE

Comment: Hi Serg - Originally I did have a WHERE, but just took it out for this example - even with my where conditions I still have the same issue.

Comment: add this line before END and tell me whether it works: where MAIN_TABLE.METRIC_NAME IN('***METRIC1***','***METRIC2***')